# Is "Guten Morgen" in the accusative? Are all greetings so?

Tags: phrase, adjective, accusative, adjective-ending, grammar-identification

After looking up the [declension of "gut"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gut#German), I would expect to see "guter Morgen" as opposed to "guten Morgen". The only conclusion I can draw is that "guten Morgen" is in the accusative case. Am I correct in assuming this? Are all greetings in the accusative? Is there a name for this grammatical category? It brings to mind the "accusative of exclamation" found in Greek and Latin, although I believe that is a bit different (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Perhaps because you can see the greeting as short for "Ich wünsche dir einen guten Morgen."?

Comment: @IQV That's interesting, but can you back it up with sources?

Comment: @ktm5124 That needs no sources. It's basic understanding of grammar.

Comment: I think every greeting in most languages is such a short form.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are correct. "Guten Morgen" is short for "Ich wünsche dir/Ihnen einen guten Morgen".

Likewise, "Guten Tag" is short for "Ich wünsche dir/Ihnen einen guten Tag". Same with "Guten Abend".

As you can see, this is just the regular accusative, so there is no need for a special name.

Comment: The same is true for basically anything else one could wish sb., like "Guten Appetit" or "Gutes neues Jahr".

Comment: @QBrute you can't really spot the difference in the last one, now can you?

Comment: @PierreArlaud What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: @QBrute that it would be "gutes neues Jahr" in nominative case too?

Comment: @PierreArlaud So? That doesn't change the fact that "Gutes neues Jahr" is accusative like OP asked and can be used as abbreviation for "Ich wünsche dir ein gutes neues Jahr". Therefore it falls under the same category as the other examples. I don't really see the problem here.

Comment: @QBrute just to close the discussion I don't remember saying there was a problem.

Comment: @QBrute Pierre Arlaud is completely right in saying that we cannot know that "Gutes neues Jahr" is in the accusative, so it's not a fact, it's a reasonable assumption.

Comment: @RHa I think it's more correct to say that "Guten Morgen" (probably) comes from a phrase like "Ich wünsche dir/Ihnen einen guten Morgen", not that it is short for it. If it were short for it, shouldn't I be able to reply something like _Ich dir auch!_?

Comment: @sgf "Dir auch!" sounds possible but really strange.

Comment: @xehpuk Doesn't sound strange to my ear. It is a reasonably common reply here in north-western Germany.